# django-allauth: email confirmation

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

i've set up django-allauth and using email confirmation when new users register which works fine

but in the confirmation email, i get

```
Hello from example.com!

    You're receiving this e-mail because user abc13 at example.com has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.

    To confirm this is correct, go to http://<mysite>.com/accounts/confirm-email/q3rknxpflshgwddlbjw6aqzlr1ayqtnfrtezucoq2ysmfbm2etcldusq5dyrcoap/

    Thank you from example.com!
    example.com
```

How can i replace "example.com" with my website name?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update the [Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site) entry in the Django admin. You can access this at:

```
http://<yoursite>.com/admin/sites/site/
```

Comment: and don't forget to add SITE_ID on settings.py and also adding django.contrib.sites to installed_apps otherwise we'll get an error with a clue. it's pretty good error message because it's tell us straight to the point that we need django.contrib.sites added to installed_apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a fully customised email with something like:

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_signed_up_(sender,request,user,**kwargs):

    subject, from_email, to = 'Welcome', 'admin@mysite', 'person@somewhere'
    text_content ="some custom text or html"
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Comment: where does this function go?

Comment: if you do this you will need to disable default email under settings.py