# Why does my django allauth verification email send from 'example.com' after the domain and display name have been changed?

Tags: django, django-allauth, user-registration, email-verification

** SOLVED - see my answer below **

I'm using Django allauth to send verification emails when users register for an account. However, the emails continue to send from 'example.com' and to include the default message (also from example.com). So far I have:

- changed the domain and display names in the 'Sites' section of Django admin
- added the site ID number in settings
- set the 'DEFAULT_FROM' email in settings
- added my own email_confirmation_subject.txt and email_confirmation_message.txt under templates/account/email

When performing the registration procedure locally, the validation emails send to the terminal from the desired email address; however, the message in the body of the email remains the generic allauth message. When registering over the deployed site, at Heroku, however, the validation emails continue to show as being sent from 'example.com', both in the subject and the body of the email (even though the deployed site is up-to-date with the local).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-allauth: email confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040073/django-allauth-email-confirmation)

Comment: Thanks. I can't say for sure though. The first answer suggests changing the names under 'Sites' on admin, which - as noted above - I've already done. The second answer, about adding a function, may be of some use, but it seems to be incomplete, for one thing because , as another user pointed out, it doesn't elobarate on where the function should go. So I'm still unclear after having read that previous post on how to implement the proposed solution or on the likelihood of it succeeding, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I finally, facepalmingly, worked this out. The problem was that I didn't realize there were two django admins in play here, one for the project deployed locally and another for the project deployed on Heroku. And I had only changed the 'Sites' details for the local admin, which is why the correct message sent to the terminal when the site ran locally but 'example.com' continued to send from the deployed site on Heroku. Now that I've updated the 'Sites' section from the Heroku Django admin, the emails send as desired.